# python instance function do not find type(class)

Tags: python

TestX is class has mylist as property, mylist returns the collection of TestX objects, below is the sample code, at line #5 getting an error "'TestX' is not declared", if TestX is removed then no error code works fine, the only question here why Python do not recognize type name in same type at collection, if preemptive/system types like int, str etc.. then type name is recognized.

```
class TestX:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._mylist:list[TestX] = [] 

    def _get_mylist(self)->list[TestX]: #This line error out
        return self._mylist

    def _set_mylist(self,value):
        self._mylist = value

    mylist = property(fget=_get_mylist,fset=_set_mylist,doc="This is test")

def main():
    test = TestX()
    print(len(test.mylist))
    test.mylist = [TestX()]
    print(len(test.mylist))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "D:\code\test.py", line 1, in <module>
        class TestX:   
    File "D:\code\test.py", line 5, in TestX
        def _get_mylist(self)->list[TestX]: 
NameError: name 'TestX' is not defined
```

Comment: You should use the solution in the linked duplicate above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
def _get_mylist(self) -> list['TestX']:
```

Comment: This is *absolutely incorrect*

Comment: @Hi10 do not type annotate with `__class__`

Comment: Someone commented to better use `__class__` instead of a string, so i added it.
I removed it again to examine your objection. Using a str seems to be the preferred way.

Comment: Yes, I did test and hence edited comment to review.

Comment: @bitflip `__class__` is completely wrong. Using a string is fine, you can also use `from __future__ import annotations` and this won't raise an error anymore with `list[TestX]`, this is all explained in the linked duplicate